# CSS, HTML: How can i make the div or <p> width dynamic as the text line increses/decreses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, html, background-color

There is a line of text inside a `<div></div>` or inside `<p></p>`.
The text length changes when clicking some links.
If the text length decreases the div or p will decrease.
If the text length increases the div or p will increase.

How can i do this ?

The problem is the div or p width looks fixed and the length of text is 30% of that div or p.
The div or p has a background color. So whole div or p is colored. But what i'm trying to do is to color the portion of background of div or p, the portion that contains text of line.

Comment: I think you need to post your html and, at the very least, your current JavaScript (assuming that you're using JavaScript to handle the link-clicks)...

Comment: if the width is fixed then maybe using jquery you would have to change that if the length is bigger than the width of the div or p

Comment: This is the html code=> `<p class="customnotice"><%= flash[:notice] %></p>` , if i use this css rule => `p.customnotice {
 margin-left: 10px;
 background: #C73E14;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 font-size: 140%;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding: 5px;
 display: inline-block;
}`, it looks like it works, but where there is no text, i get a red squared box in home page in place of the `<p>..</p>` element. Why am i getting that red box? How can i remove that red box?

Comment: Now i got the reason, the red squared box comes because of `padding: 5px`. But i need to do padding. So what should i do? What's the solution?

Comment: Ahh, guru, you should have mentioned you were doing rails. That changes things.

Comment: @Hexxagonal, What's the problem with using rails? Why does it change things?

Comment: Nothing wrong with rails. I love rails. It just changed the answer you were looking for (which it looks like it worked for you).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, you're doing Rails! Ok, here's your real answer.  Just check to see if the `flash[:notice]` exists before displaying it to the screen.

```
<% if flash[:notice] %>
  <p class="customnotice"><%= flash[:notice] %></p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3):

Wrap the text in a `<span></span>` and style that instead?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds to me like you're struggling with the difference between an inline and block level element, but forget about that a second and let's get to what you want. **Without seeing your code...** an easy way to fix that is to make your block level elements p and div float to the left.  From what you've said, this should be close to what you want ([check the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EJeHx/)).

```
div {
    float:left;
    background:red;
}
```

Ok, so what is a block level element? A div and p are block level elements. [As per the Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTML/Block-level_elements) "Their most significant characteristic is that they typically are formatted with a line break before and after the element (thereby creating a stand-alone block of content)." This is why with default styling it expands to the entire line. This sounds like exactly what you didn't want. Where as a span will shrink down to fit just the content that it contains.

If you want a more complicated "real-world" example, [I've thrown together this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AVbLd/) that might help you down your path.